# How to take in multiple scanf inputs from a previous variable

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a code that takes in multiple values using `scanf()`. Depending on what the previous input was. Like for example

```
printf("enter how many trips you are taking:");
scanf("%f", &trip)

printf("please enter the cost of each trip:");
```

^--im having trouble figuring out how to scan in multiple input values without limiting the number of input value of cost

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer would be to read the values in a loop:

```
float *trip_costs;
trip_costs = malloc(trip * sizeof(*trip_costs));

for (i=0; i<trip; i++)
    scanf("%f", trip_costs + i);
```

Also note that since you're using it for a count, `trip` would probably be better off as an integer type.

Comment: the only problem is my professor is requiring us to take this input with only the minmume use of for while and if loops without using any thing else

Comment: @Thao: one loop is pretty minimal. If you really want to do it without an (explicit) loop, Fortran provides that, but C really doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a single `scanf()` call will do (as I'm assuming you were hoping it would). The format string is constructible, but the actual function call is not, in the sense that you wouldn't be able to have the number of destination pointer arguments <s>conditionally</s> variably determined at runtime. You should use a loop a la Jerry Coffin's answer.